# How can I calculate between two dates per User Pseudo ID for specific events?

Tags: looker-studio

I linked Firebase to BigQuery and start using Google Data Studio to create a table to list users by "User Pseudo ID".

My goal is to calculate the difference between two dates, the date of `first_open` and the date of `app_remove` to come up with an average retention time.

How can I write the right query in Data Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using the three step process below:

### 1) `HH:MM:SS`

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below uses the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function to find the difference between `app_remove` and `first_open`, and displays the difference in `SECOND` (for future reference, set the third input [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) as required, for example, to view the difference in days, set the input to `DAY`):

```
DATETIME_DIFF(app_remove, first_open, SECOND)
```

### 2) Type (`HH:MM:SS`)

```
Number > Duration (Sec.)
```

### 3) Aggregation (`HH:MM:SS`)

```
AVG
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b907408d-a601-4c3f-bf95-92ce2f3fe263) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[DATE_DIFF](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583307?hl=en) may be what you are looking for.

That is if `first_open` and `app_remove` are date fields or date expressions